# StreamReader weird error with �

Tags: c#, streamreader

StreamReader reads '–' (alt+ 0150) as � even if I have UTF-8 encoding and I have detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks (BOM) set to true. Can any one guide me on this ?

Comment: Have you tried Unicode encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That byte code won't appear in utf-8 encoded text.  It is '\u2013', 0xe2 + 0x80 + 0x93 when encoded in utf-8.  If you get this character when you type Alt+0150 on the numeric keypad then your default system code page is probably 1252.  Simply pass Encoding.Default to the StreamReader constructor.

Comment: Perfect 
Default encoding without detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter works. You guys are awsome thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the encoding that was used to encode the text. There's no way around that. Try different encodings until you get the desired results.

From MSDN:

> The detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter detects the encoding by
>   looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically
>   recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text
>   if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise,
>   the user-provided encoding is used. See the Encoding.GetPreamble
>   method for more information.

Which means that using that BOM is just an extra thing that may or may not work or can be easily overriden

Comment: Yup am trying other encodings

Comment: Good point about using detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As the other users wrote, the probable reason of this issue is an ANSI encoding of the file you are trying to read. I've recreated the issue you've described when I saved the file in ANSI encoding.

Try to use this code:

```
 var stream = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.Default);
```

The *Encoding.Default* parameter is important in here. This code should read the character you've mentioned correctly.