# C# Streamreader: Handling of special characters \" \' etc

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm reading then writing a text file.  Before and after the data of interest the file contains many lines that should remain unaltered.  But streamreader seems to convert the special characters ( `"` `'` `—` ) into other characters that appear as funky diamonds in both C# textboxes and in notepad.  How can text get passed through file read/write operations completely unaltered?  Thanks.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sOutputFileName);
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sTempFileName))
{
   while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
   {
       rdBuffer = sr.ReadLine();
       txtProgressDisplay.Text += rdBuffer + "\r\n";

       // parse and process some lines here

       wrBuffer = rdBuffer;
       sw.WriteLine(wrBuffer);
       txtProgressDisplay.Text += wrBuffer + "\r\n";
   }
   sr.Close();
}
sw.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [StreamReader weird error with �](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128199/streamreader-weird-error-with)

Comment: `StreamReader` does no such thing - are you sure you are using the right encoding?

Comment: They are not exactly special characters, unless the file was created by a word processor.  Use a hex viewer to look at the file, document the hex codes you saw for those characters.

Comment: UTF-8 issue you need to something like this.. follow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318850/streamwriter-erroneous-characters

Answer (score 4):

I am almost certain the issue is related to character encoding, ie UTF8, ASCII, UTF7, etc.  Try creating your `StreamReader` passing in the correct encoding,

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sTempFileName, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
```

You can use `Encoding.ASCII`, `Encoding.UTF7`, etc

Comment: Yes, you have a correct answer thanks.  ASCII encoding fixed the problem. (Of course I tried the others; Unicode, UTF8, Default.)  It also seems likely my test file has a bogus encoding scheme.  Thank you all for the quick responses.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be something with encoding.

1) Check that your text viewer is using the same encoding as your .NET application (maybe UTF-8?).

2) Check if the file itself has been created using the same encoding as your .NET application too (*are you mixing characters in different encodings?*).

Comment: Yes, you have a correct answer thanks.  ASCII encoding fixed the problem. (Of course I tried the others; Unicode, UTF8, Default.)  It also seems likely my test file has a bogus encoding scheme.  Thank you all for the quick responses.