# StreamWriter erroneous characters

Tags: c#

Having an problem where streamwriter is producing erroneous characters in a csv that I'm producing. The characters, **ï»¿** , only appear at the start of the file:

```
ï»¿5,"GEN",555555555,,"Evan","Smith",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"email@someplace.com"
5,"GEN",555555555,,"Dorathy","Smith",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"email@someplace.com"
5,"GEN",555555555,,"Marvin","Smith",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"email@someplace.com"
....
```

Looks to me like an encoding problem. I've tried different encoding and also a regex to clean the string with little luck. Here's the code for preview (although it's nothing complex). Also it's running as a web process.

```
string fileName = includeEmail == false ? "attachment; filename=stuacct_batch.txt" : "attachment; filename=rentals.csv";
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", fileName);
Context.Response.ContentType = includeEmail == false ? "text/plain" : "text/csv";

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{   
    string line = "";
    foreach (Student s in students)
    {
        // ... some logic above that that's misc. to this problem 
        line = "5,\"GEN\"," + s.StudentNumber + ",,\"" + s.FirstName + "\",\"" + s.LastName + "\",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\"" + s.Email + "\"";
        sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

Context.Response.End();
Context.Response.Flush();
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: @Lynn unfortunately the client takes the file and loads it into another program. I called the developer and did not know the encoding of their software. Interesting note, OpenOffice will display the chars., but NotePad++ w/ or w/out BOM they are not displayed. Perhaps I can trap the BOM bytes?

Comment: No need to trap them; per Martin's answer below, change your StreamWriter to output ASCII instead of UTF, and you shouldn't see them anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have specified that you want to use UTF-8 encoding for the stream and those initial bytes is a valid UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM). The problem is apparently that your viewer/editor doesn't decode the UTF-8 stream correctly. If it only is the BOM that is the problem and you want to create a stream without a BOM you can create your own instance of the [`UTF8Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx) class:

```
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream, encoding)) ...
```

In case you really want to work with ASCII data you should use that encoding instead:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.ASCII)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are probably characters designating that the file is unicode, and not ansi.

Are you opening the file as an ANSI file, in a text editor? If so, that's why you're seeing the characters. Either try opening it as unicode, or set your encoding to not be unicode.

Comment: For more information, those bytes are UTF-8 BOM bytes.  They will not show in a text editor that understands BoM.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark