# C# StreamWriter outputting in Japanese

Tags: c#, streamwriter

For some strange reason, I'm reading data from a .txt (notepad) file and I want to strip just the first 5-digit number. After the program runs, my output file is being printed in what I assume is Japanese. I will post some code, as well as sample input and output below. Any help would be appreciated in tracking down why this is happening. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BasicFileStripper
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\MillerEpicOutputs\ClientIds.txt");
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\MillerEpicOutputs\j.txt");//, encoding);
        string line;
        int count = 0;
        write.Write("{");
        while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            count++;
            string copy = line.Substring(0, 5);
            write.Write(copy + ",");
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        write.WriteLine("};");
        write.WriteLine("Count: " + count);
        write.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Sample Input:

```
68669 - (DO NOT USE)
68363 - 100 Men of Blue Hills
68364 - 10484 Marty LLC
68365 - 21st Century Therapy
69006 - 21st Century Therapy PC
69007 - 31 Dodge Partnership
69008 - 34 Merriam, LLC
69009 - 3525 Sage Council of Co-Owners
```

Sample Output:
㙻㘸㤶㘬㌸㌶㘬㌸㐶㘬㌸㔶㘬〹㘰㘬〹㜰㘬〹㠰㘬〹㤰㘬〹〱㜬㄰㐹㜬

Comment: Have you tried switching the encoding on the text editor you're using to view the output file to see if that was the problem?

Comment: I'm using notepad, which I thought didn't encode data at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're trying to read the output in Notepad (see ([this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts)). Use the [`StreamWriter(String, Boolean, Encoding)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt.aspx) with [`Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx), which will cause a BOM to be written to the output file, making Notepad read it properly. If you don't need to read it in Notepad, leave it as is, and note that anything else that reads it and expects it to be UTF-8 will read it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> Those are probably characters designating that the file is unicode, and not ansi.
>
> Are you opening the file as an ANSI file, in a text editor? If so, that's why you're seeing >the characters. Either try opening it as unicode, or set your encoding to not be unicode.

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318850/streamwriter-erroneous-characters)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the proper encoding for the saved file. That is why you are ending up with Japanese characters. If you don't consume the data as a file, there is no real issue. If you are consuming it as a file, you need to encode it properly so it is readable.